# Which object I can use to read xlsx tempate

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have an xlsx file that I use as a template.

I am tring to create a new excel file using this template
how can I read this file and write it to a new xlsx file 
in python 27?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to install the Excel module xlutils at http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: this package is for xls. and not for xlsx. :(

Comment: also, this post could be useful for opening existing xlsx sheets (since xlsxwriter does not have the open option - but you can save): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002133/xlsxwriter-is-there-a-way-to-open-an-existing-worksheet-in-my-workbook

Answer (score 0):

You can use openpyxl to edit existing xlsx files or save them as new files.