# Python xlsxwriter - add a worksheet to an existing workbook

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am doing my first steps with xlswriter.

I have an existing workbook `test.xlsx`, and I want to add to it a new worksheet - `sheet 2`.

what I tried is the following:

```
import xlsxwriter as xl
xbook=xl.Workbook('test.xlsx')
xbook.add_worksheet('sheet2')
```

The problem with this is that it overrides all the other sheets in the workbook. 
How can I add a worksheet without overriding all the other worksheets in the workbook?

Comment: Hey you can use [**openpyxl**](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.3/tutorial.html#create-a-workbook) for that and of course it works perfectly with **.xlsx** files

Comment: Can you explain how? 
I tried:

    `from openpyxl import load_workbook \n
    wb=load_workbook('test.xlsx') \n
    ws=wb.create_sheet() \n
    ws.title="sheet 2"`

but the sheet was not created!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is still possible with xlsxwriter. Please take a look at this answer for [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25121481/2599266)