# pandas.ExcelWriter ValueError: Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I want to add some records to an excel file and I use `pandas.ExcelWriter` to do this(http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html?highlight=excelwriter#pandas.ExcelWriter
):

```
import pandas as pd                                                     

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[4], 'b':['corn'], 'c':[0.5]})              

with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", mode='a') as writer: 
            df.to_excel(writer)
```

a, b, c are titles name of test.xlsx

run this program, raise a valueError:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c643d22b4217> in <module>
----> 1 with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", mode='a') as writer:
      2     df.to_excel(writer)
      3 

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py in __init__(self, path, engine, date_format, datetime_format, mode, **engine_kwargs)
   1935 
   1936         if mode == 'a':
-> 1937             raise ValueError('Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!')
   1938 
   1939         super(_XlsxWriter, self).__init__(path, engine=engine,

ValueError: Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!
```

I don't know why?

Answer (score 58):

Try with this:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("existing_file_name.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="name", startrow=num, startcol=num)
```

You need to specify the engine as "openpyxl".

Comment: Doesn't work when using `io.BytesIO()` instead of "existing_file_name.xlsx"

Comment: Only the wlxt engine was deprecated in pandas 1.2.0 [(see docs)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter). In fact, specifying `engine="openpyxl"` solved the error for me (in pandas 1.4.3)

Comment: This appends the data by always adding a new sheet, even if a sheet with the specified name exists. I understood the question (and your answer) to mean 'append the data to the table in this sheet, throw an exception if headers are not appropriate'

Answer (score 9):

Try specifying the 'engine' as openpyxl:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)
```

Answer (score 4):

As the traceback says, `ValueError: Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!`

I can't answer your question, *why*, this is a decision of the Pandas developers.

But I was able to make your use-case work with Pandas 0.24 and `openpyxl`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[4], 'b':['corn'], 'c':[0.5]})              

with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", mode='a') as writer: 
            df.to_excel(writer)
```

Comment: Do you have `openpyxl`?

Comment: using `conda list` showing openpyxl has been installed

Comment: Yes. `openpyxl` is separate from Pandas.

Comment: try `conda install openpyxl` and try it again. and maybe `conda uninstall xlsxwriter`

Comment: I uninstall xlsxwriter, my case can run normally, but when I open `test.xlsx`, the record  were not successfully add to excel file.

Comment: After trying the suggestion made by @JoshFriedlander please follow the below url to append dataframes to the same sheet:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737220/append-dataframe-to-excel-with-pandas

Answer (score 1):

hum, i am pretty sure you could no use the function append to an existing xlsx file with xlsxwriter, because xlsxwriter library is only for writing excel files

[See the issue on Github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3441)

so you could use openpyxl or better write your program to do this function..

but if you look at code inside this libray, it just reads the file in temp environment before writes the final file, its not a real append...

Answer (score 1):

solved it, use a capital A in mode, that does the trick!

```
    import pandas as pd                                                     

    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[4], 'b':['corn'], 'c':[0.5]})              

    with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", mode='A') as writer: 
        df.to_excel(writer)
```

Comment: yeah this worked for me too. why would it be though? I looked through the documentation and nowhere is there any mention of a 'A' mode. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter

Comment: I have no idea too, I tried this without realizing that my keyboard had Caps lock on!

Comment: This does not actually open the file in append mode.

Comment: it's the same that `mode='w'`