# Pandas write to different sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.DataFrame(dataset)
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter("C:/adhoc/test.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test')
writer.save()
```

I have two sheets, Sheet1 and Test. When I run the code it is deleting Sheet1 and just writing the data onto Test. What am I doing wrong here? Expected output I want is to not write anything on Sheet1 and have the data written to Test.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use append as the file mode in the `ExcelWriter`. But append does not supported with the xlsxwriter.

To append you need to specify the engine as [`openpyxl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863238/pandas-excelwriter-valueerror-append-mode-is-not-supported-with-xlsxwriter)

This will write the data to the Test sheet and leave the Sheet1 as it is.

```py
import pandas

file_path = "C:/adhoc/test.xlsx"

data = pandas.DataFrame(dataset)
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test')
writer.save()
```

Alternatively, you can use [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) here:

```py
import pandas

file_path = "C:/adhoc/test.xlsx"
data = pandas.DataFrame(dataset)

with pandas.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test')
```