# How to write in my excel file by taking data from an HTML form under the previous data in next rows?

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask

This is my basic flask route

```py
@app.route('/home/form', methods=('GET','POST'))            
def form():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        machine = request.form['machine']
        df = pd.DataFrame([[machine]], columns=["Machine"])
        with pd.ExcelWriter('P:\\Rohaan\\LATEST WEBSITE\\sample.xlsx') as writer:
            df.to_excel(writer)

        if not machine:
            flash('Title is required!')
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('form.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[image]

**My form.html that I retrieve data frame**

**HTML Code**

```
<form method="post">
  <label for="Machine">Machine</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="machine"
        placeholder="Message machine"
        value=''></input>
  <br>

  <label for="content">Message Content</label>
  <br>
  <textarea name="content"
            placeholder="Message content"
            rows="15"
            cols="60"
            ></textarea>
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Currently getting this result using this code**

[image]

My question is:

Why the incoming data override my previous data?

Comment: When trying now, what is happening?

Comment: currently it is clearing the whole data in excel file and making a new entry

Comment: What do you mean by "making a new entry"

Comment: kindly check my answer

Comment: what the html that you are render?

Comment: I got the code limit, by the way I have answered my HTML code

Answer (score 0):

**Currently getting this result using this code**

```
@app.route('/home/form', methods=('GET','POST'))
def form():

if request.method == 'POST':
    machine = request.form['machine']
    df = pd.DataFrame([[machine]], columns=["Machine"])
    with pd.ExcelWriter('P:\\Rohaan\\LATEST WEBSITE\\sample.xlsx') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer)

    if not machine:
        flash('Title is required!')
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
return render_template('form.html')
if name == "main": app.run(debug=True)
```

[image]

Comment: you should put it in the question

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) you should specify `mode = "a"` if you want to append and not override (default is `mode = "w"`) inside ExcelWriter, but if it is actually supported is probably dependent on the chosen excel engine.

Comment: ValueError: Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!

Comment: Exactly as i said it is dependent on used engine, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863238/pandas-excelwriter-valueerror-append-mode-is-not-supported-with-xlsxwriter)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Code**

```
<form method="post">
  <label for="Machine">Machine</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="machine"
        placeholder="Message machine"
        value=''></input>
  <br>

  <label for="content">Message Content</label>
  <br>
  <textarea name="content"
            placeholder="Message content"
            rows="15"
            cols="60"
            ></textarea>
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You should put it in the question