# Export the form information as rows in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Edited

I have a similar previous post, but this one is different.

I made an interface, but it doesn't work the way I want.

If you click the `Create empty Excel` button, an excel is created with the `headers` in the columns. Until this step everything works fine.

What I tried to do: By pressing the `ok` button, the information written in the form is exported as a row in Excel. But I have a problem: The information is added as a column and the previous information is deleted. The aforementioned corresponds to the function `def Excel_information (self):` .This function is the one that I must write well, but I don't know how

```
import sys, re
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDialog, QFormLayout, QCheckBox, QComboBox, QSpinBox, QDialogButtonBox, QMessageBox, QErrorMessage, QToolTip, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QLabel, QTextEdit, QMainWindow, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import ctypes
import pandas as pd
import os.path
import os
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import workbook
import openpyxl


headers = ['Fecha', 'Dias abiertos', 'Nombre del caso', 'Responsable', 'Ok Mkt' , 'Solicitud Lotus' ,'OS' , 'Monto' , 'Fecha de cierre' , 'Comentario']

class Dialog(QDialog):
    NumGridRows = 10
    NumButtons = 4

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.createFormGroupBox()
        
        self.setStyleSheet("QDialog {background:rgb(66,85,99);}")
        
        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        buttonBox1 = QPushButton('Create empty Excel',self)
        buttonBox1.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(255,199,44);")
        buttonBox1.clicked.connect(self.export_excel)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.Excel_information)
        buttonBox.setStyleSheet("background:rgb(255,199,44);")
      
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox1)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Cuadro seguimiento")

    def createFormGroupBox(self):
        
        self.Fecha= QLineEdit(self)
        self.Diasabiertos =QLineEdit(self)
        self.Nombredelcaso=QLineEdit(self)
        self.Responsable=QLineEdit(self)
        self.OkMkt=QLineEdit(self)
        self.Solicitudlotus= QLineEdit(self)
        self.Os=QLineEdit(self)
        self.Monto=QLineEdit(self)
        self.Fechacierre=QLineEdit(self)
        self.Comentario=QLineEdit(self)
        
        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Python")
        self.formGroupBox.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox, QLabel {color: rgb(255,199,44);}")
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Fecha"), self.Fecha)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Dias abiertos"), self.Diasabiertos)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Nombre del caso"), self.Nombredelcaso)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Responsable"), self.Responsable)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Ok MKT"), self.OkMkt)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Solicitud Lotus"), self.Solicitudlotus)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("OS"), self.Os)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Monto"), self.Monto)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Fecha cierre"), self.Fechacierre)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Comentario"), self.Comentario)
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)
        

    def export_excel (self):
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)
        writer= ExcelWriter(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop\\') + r'New.xlsx')
        df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet 1' , index=0)
        writer.save()

    
    def Excel_information(self):
        Fecha1= str(self.Fecha.text())
        Diasabiertos1= str(self.Diasabiertos.text())
        Nombredelcaso1= str(self.Nombredelcaso.text())
        Responsable1= str(self.Responsable.text())
        OkMkt1= str(self.Fecha.text())
        Solicitudlotus1= str(self.Solicitudlotus.text())
        Os1= str(self.Os.text())
        Monto1= str(self.Monto.text())
        Fechacierre1= str(self.Fechacierre.text())
        Comentario1= str(self.Comentario.text())
        
        fill_form= [Fecha1, Diasabiertos1, Nombredelcaso1, Responsable1, OkMkt1, Solicitudlotus1, Os1, Monto1, Fechacierre1, Comentario1 ]
        df = pd.DataFrame(fill_form)
        path = (os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop\\') + r'New.xlsx')
        wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
        sheet = wb['Sheet 1']
        
        try:
            writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in wb.worksheets)
            reader = pd.read_excel(path)
            df.to_excel(path,index=False,header=False,startrow=len(reader)+1)
            writer.close()
            
        except:
            with pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
            
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    sys.exit(dialog.exec_())
```

Comment: A simplest way would be attaching a timestamp to your filename that way it will create a new file.

Comment: I need to know if what I am asking is confusing, to edit the post

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075046/8601641) works for you or not.

Comment: The answer of this question is here: [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737220/append-dataframe-to-excel-with-pandas?fbclid=IwAR1PZ2fGjOKy8y6NkjrvpKKGb-DcdbV9COJg2bVQd-umQrDRkSJ4XckCZ1s]

Answer (score 0):

Before you recreate the Excel file, you should check whether it exists (using os.path.exists, for instance). If it does, you can retrieve the information before recreation.