# Pandas - Need to add 2 dataframes with a same CSV in subsequent rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to write two dataframe lists to a CSV in 2 rows, and in future i need add few more rows. I am using below, the first dataframe works fine sucessfully not the second one

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ("input.csv")
#From column name Test2 take count value of entry which is simple
simp = df.Test2.value_counts().Simple
medium = df.Test2.value_counts().Medium
list1 = [2, 5, 3, 3, 3]
list2 = [5, 10, 5, 5, 5]
#multiplying the above list value with the count of simple from input CSV
simplelist = [i * simp for i in list1]
mediumlist = [i * medium for i in list2]
print(simplelist)
print(mediumlist)
#[24, 60, 36, 36, 36]
#[60, 120, 60, 60, 60]
# till here its working. Its printing as expected 
# I need to write the CSV with above value 1 to 5 from above list with Type as Simple and Medium
columns=['Type', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4', 'Value5']
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Simple'] + simplelist], columns=columns)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['Medium'] + mediumlist], columns=columns)
# I can use below to add first row but df2, I am not sure how to add that the second dataframe df2. PLease help
df1.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

It should as below for me.

```
Type  Value1  Value2  Value3    Value4      Value5
Simple  24       60       36      36       36 (Working)
Medium  60      120      60       60       60  (Can not figure how to add this)
```

Please help, how can I add the second dataframe, please do needf

Comment: Please post your dataframe.

Comment: @Pygirl  Type  Value1  Value2  Value3    Value4      Value5
                 Simple  24       60       36      36       36 
                 Medium  60      120      60       60       60

Comment: Does this answer your question? [append dataframe to excel with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737220/append-dataframe-to-excel-with-pandas)

Comment: You should look into DataFrame.append