# How to append dataframe to excel

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe which I save it into an excel file at a certain location.
Currently I do this way:

```
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\user_name\Downloads\test.xlsx')
```

Issue I am facing is when I insert the new dataframe it overwrites old ones. I want to append the new data. I tried several SOF answers but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Have you contemplated reading the xlsx file to python as a data frame, appending the data in python, and then saving the resultant df over the old file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first `read_excel`, `append` and then write back `to_excel`:

```
filename = r'C:\Users\user_name\Downloads\test.xlsx'
existing = df.read_excel(filename)
output = existing.append(df)
output.to_excel(filename)
```

To check if the file exists before reading, you can use:

```
import os

filename = r'C:\Users\user_name\Downloads\test.xlsx'
if os.path.exists(filename):
    existing = df.read_excel(filename)
    output = existing.append(df)
else:
    output = df
output.to_excel(filename)
```

Comment: In certain cases the excel might not exist, the above command I use creates an excel file as well.

Comment: You can use **os.path.isfile** to check whether a file exist. Then use the output boolean and either append or create the file.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle it is that you could read what is in Excel and combine it with your data frame, then overwrite the excel file/ generate it again basically.

Here's a sample of a similar question asked where a solution can be found with excel writer. Instead of overwriting the existing data, they just carefully set a startrow by reading the existing file for the startrow.

The last row/ start row can be found with the command writer.sheets[sheetname].max_row

[append dataframe to excel with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737220/append-dataframe-to-excel-with-pandas)

```
import pandas
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}

for sheetname in writer.sheets:
    df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheetname, startrow=writer.sheets[sheetname].max_row, index = False,header= False)

writer.save()
```