# Export multiple dataframes in one excel tab

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to Export or save pandas multiple Dataframe in one excel tab. Let's suppose my df's are below and need to export it the same way in the excel all together in one tab.

```
 df1:
Id  Name    Rank
1   Scott   4
2   Jennie  8
3   Murphy  1

df2:
Id  Name    Rank
1   John     14
2   Brown    18
3   Claire   11

df3:
Id  Name    Rank
1   Shenzen   84
2   Dass      58
3   Ghouse    31

df4:
Id  Name    Rank
1   Zen     104
2   Ben     458
3   Susuie  198
```

Comment: Refer the solution her : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737220/append-dataframe-to-excel-with-pandas

Comment: How can I keep only one header at the top and remove the bottom headers for other dataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through a list of your dfs and use [**`pandas.ExcelWriter`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) :

```
import pandas as pd

list_df = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
df1.name = 'df1'
df2.name = 'df2'
df3.name = 'df3'
df4.name = 'df4'

sr = 0

with pd.ExcelWriter('your_excel_name.xlsx') as writer:
    for df in list_df:
        df.to_excel(writer, startrow=sr, sheet_name='your_sheet_name', index=False)
        workbook  = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
        title = df.name + ':'
        worksheet.write(sr-1, 0, title)
        sr += (df.shape[0] + 3)
```

> **Note** : The dataframes will be put in the same sheet and separated by one single empty row. You can adjust this by changing the value of `(df.shape[0] + 3)`.

##### Output (in Excel)

[image]

##### Edit :

If you wanna keep only one header for all the dataframes, use this :

```
sr = df1.shape[0]+4
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, startrow=1, index=False)
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    title = df1.name + ':'
    worksheet.write(0, 0, title)
    for df in list_df[1:]:
        df.to_excel(writer, startrow=sr, index=False, header=False)
        workbook  = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
        title = df.name + ':'
        worksheet.write(sr-1, 0, title)
        sr += (df.shape[0] + 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I dont need to concatenate  records. I need to export the file the same way as I have posted above (from top to bottom rows). 
In first 5 rows df1s output
Next rows df2s output and so on

Comment: I updated my answer. Check it out !

Comment: I also want to display header for the first dataframe only and remove headers for the other dataframes display below. How can I do that?

Comment: Take a look on the Edit/Workaround I put in the end of my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is exactly I was looking for and I learned new tricks today with your help :)