# Append data to excel sheet with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have an excel sheet I am need to add new data without deleting old data I am trying many times and Posted on Discord Servers many times and posting on stack overflow and don't getting solution for this If anyone can help me I will be very thankful for him because I missed my deadline with my client.
If someone want to help me by sharing my screen with them and speaking, No Problem my English is not bad

**Discord Tag: Nour Eldin#9789**

My Code:

```py
editableExcelSheet = ExcelWriter(
    r'D:\Projects\MOJ\MOJ.xlsx',
    mode="a",
    engine="openpyxl",
    if_sheet_exists="overlay",
)
serialNumberFromSheet_htmlName = request.form.get("serialNumberFromSheet_htmlName")
dataSet = {'SerialNumber': [serialNumberFromSheet_htmlName],
newCase = pd.DataFrame(dataSet)
newCase.to_excel(editableExcelSheet, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737220/append-dataframe-to-excel-with-pandas