# Can I create Python Pandas ExcelWriter format without pre-creating a workbook object?

Tags: python, pandas, format, xlsxwriter

I want to create a fixed format for ExcelWriter in Pandas which I could use in many scripts, without needing to write it everytime. I know I can create a format with:

```
import pandas as pd
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook = writer.book
num_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.0'})
```

And then use `num_fmt` with:

```
worksheet.set_column('H:H', 8, num_fmt)
```

But I'm looking for a way to avoid re-defining `num_fmt` in every script I write. I have a self-defined package named `my_pack` that I import to every script, and I want to somehow define `num_fmt` **there**, so I could use it like:

```
worksheet.set_column('H:H', 8, my_pack.num_fmt)
```

without defining `num_fmt` in the current script.
Is that possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002133/xlsxwriter-is-there-a-way-to-open-an-existing-worksheet-in-my-workbook

Answer (score 1):

> I have a self-defined package named my_pack that I import to every script, and I want to somehow define num_fmt there ... without defining num_fmt in the current script. Is that possible?

No. Not with XlsxWriter.

You need to instantiate a format from a Workbook object and it is unique to each workbook, so you won't be able to create it once, store it, and then reuse it in different workbooks.