# How to save an excel workbook from within python

Tags: python, excel, input, save

I'm new to python I made this code which makes you input data that is Automatticly inputted into excel.
The thing is when I run the program twice it overwrites the previous data so I need to know how to save it.
this is the code I wrote

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Book1.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

name = input('your full name: ')
age = int(input('your age: '))
emaill = input('your email: ')


idontknow = (
    ['Name', name],
    ['Age', age],
    ['Email', emaill],
)
row = 0
col = 0
for item, cost in idontknow:
    worksheet.write(row, col, item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
    row += 1
workbook.close()
```

any suggestion will help

Comment: well you're starting from 0,0 every time, so you're writing into the same cells. You need to see where the data already in the sheet ends, and set row/col to values large enough not to overwrite the old data.

Comment: actually, I just looked it up: you can't read or modify excel files using xlsxwriter, only write them. If you need to read/modify, use a different library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xlsxwriter: is there a way to open an existing worksheet in my workbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002133/xlsxwriter-is-there-a-way-to-open-an-existing-worksheet-in-my-workbook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the pandas library to perform the data manipulation. A code that performs the task you indicate would be the following:

```
import pandas as pd

#read the file and make a DataFrame
data = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#get the data
name = input('your full name: ')
age = int(input('your age: '))
email = input('your email: ')

#get the last edited row
row = len(df)

#write the data
df.loc[row, 'name'] = name
df.loc[row, 'age'] = age
df.loc[row, 'email'] = email

#save the file
df.to_excel('Book1.xlsx',index=False)
```

Additionally, this code allows you to have headers for each column in your file, which is convenient in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

`openpyxl` provide more functionality in parsing excel files, with similar syntax as `xlsxwriter`. (`worksheet.max_row` for example is accessible in `openpyxl` but not in `xlsxwriter`)

```
import openpyxl

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.create_sheet(0)

name = input('your full name: ')
age = int(input('your age: '))
emaill = input('your email: ')


idontknow = (
    ['Name', name],
    ['Age', age],
    ['Email', emaill],
)

row = worksheet.max_row + 1
for item, cost in idontknow:
    worksheet.cell(row=row, column=0, value=item)
    worksheet.cell(row=row, column=1, value=cost)
    row += 1
workbook.save('Book1.xlsx')
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using "csv" - https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html
excel can read and save to csv format, and I find it easier to work with.